# Why won't yield return from within a `.map` callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, ecmascript-6

[Learn Generators - 4 » CATCH ERROR!](https://github.com/isRuslan/learn-generators/blob/master/exercises/catch_error/problem.md)
The solution uses a `for loop` but I just couldn't find anything in [MDN - Iteration Protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) that refers to yield within callbacks.

I'm going to guess the answer is just `don't do that` but thanks in advance if anyone has the time or inclination to provide an explanation!

**Code:**

```
function *upper (items) {
  items.map(function (item) {
    try {
      yield item.toUpperCase()
    } catch (e) {
      yield 'null'
    }
  }
}

var badItems = ['a', 'B', 1, 'c']

for (var item of upper(badItems)) {
  console.log(item)
}
// want to log: A, B, null, C
```

**Error:**

```
⇒  learn-generators run catch-error-map.js
/Users/gyaresu/programming/projects/nodeschool/learn-generators/catch-error-map.js:4
      yield item.toUpperCase() // error below
            ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

**Even my editor knows this is a terrible idea...**

[image: yield within callback]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of [Learn generators](https://github.com/isRuslan/learn-generators/) workshopper*.

Answer by @slebetman is kinda correct and I also can add more:

Yes, [MDN - Iteration Protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_.22iterable.22_protocol) doesn't refer directly about `yield` within callbacks.
But, it tell us about importance from where you `yield` item, because you can only  use `yield` inside *generators*. See [MDN - Iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterables) docs to find out more.

[@marocchino](https://github.com/marocchino) [suggest](https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/1186#issuecomment-106232506) just fine solution iterate over Array that was changed after map:

```
function *upper (items) {
  yield* items.map(function (item) {
    try {
      return item.toUpperCase();
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  });
}
```

We can do it, because Array has iteration mechanism, see [Array.prototype[@@iterator]()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator).

```
var bad_items = ['a', 'B', 1, 'c'];

for (let item of bad_items) {
  console.log(item); // a B 1 c
}
```

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) doesn't have default iteration behavior, so we couldn't iterate over it.

But generators is not just iterators. Every generator is an iterator, but not vice versa. Generators allows you to customize iteration (and not only) process by calling `yield` keyword. You can play and see the difference between generators/iterators here:

**Demo**: [babel/repl](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20*try_to_upper(items)%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20no%20effects!%20just%20iterate%20over%20%60items%60.%0A%20%20yield%20*%20items%5BSymbol.iterator%5D(function%20*%20(item)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20try%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20item.toUpperCase()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20catch%20(e)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20'null'%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20*upper%20(items)%20%7B%0A%20%20for%20(let%20i%20in%20items)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20try%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20items%5Bi%5D.toUpperCase()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20catch%20(e)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20null%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20*items_iterator%20(items)%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20delegate%20iteration%20to%20Array%20%60items%60%0A%20%20yield%20*items%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20bad_items%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'B'%2C%201%2C%20'c'%5D%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log('iterate%20with%20wrapper')%3B%0Afor%20(let%20item%20of%20items_iterator(bad_items))%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(item)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log('iterate%20with%20plain%20Array')%3B%0Afor%20(let%20item%20of%20bad_items)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(item)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log('iterate%20with%20Symbol.iterator')%3B%0Afor%20(let%20item%20of%20try_to_upper(bad_items))%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(item)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log('iterate%20with%20upper')%3B%0Afor%20(let%20item%20of%20upper(bad_items))%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(item)%3B%0A%7D).

Comment: generally map is used to transform one array to another. Why wouldn't this  work? bit.ly/1YPHiYS  - i.e. a is undefined - is there a way?

Answer (score 19):

One problem is `yield` yields just one level to the function's caller. So when you `yield` in a callback it may not do what you think it does:

```
// The following yield:
function *upper (items) { // <---- does not yield here
  items.map(function (item) { // <----- instead it yields here
    try {
      yield item.toUpperCase()
    } catch (e) {
      yield 'null'
    }
  }
}
```

So in the code above, you have absolutely no access to the yielded value. `Array.prototype.map` does have access to the yielded value. And if you were the person who wrote the code for `.map()` you can get that value. But since you're not the person who wrote `Array.prototype.map`, and since the person who wrote `Array.prototype.map` doesn't re-yield the yielded value, you don't get access to the yielded value(s) at all (and hopefully they will be all garbage collected).

### Can we make it work?

Let's see if we can make yield work in callbacks. We can probably write a function that behaves like `.map()` for generators:

```
// WARNING: UNTESTED!
function *mapGen (arr,callback) {
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        yield callback(arr[i])
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
mapGen(items,function (item) {
    yield item.toUpperCase();
});
```

Or if you're brave you can extend `Array.prototype`:

```
// WARNING: UNTESTED!
Array.prototype.mapGen = function *mapGen (callback) {
    for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        yield callback(this[i])
    }
};
```

We can probably call it like this:

```
function *upper (items) {
  yield* items.mapGen(function * (item) {
    try {
      yield item.toUpperCase()
    } catch (e) {
      yield 'null'
    }
  })
}
```

Notice that you need to yield twice. That's because the inner yield returns to `mapGen` then `mapGen` will yield that value then you need to yield it in order to return that value from `upper`.

OK. This sort of works but not quite:

```
var u = upper(['aaa','bbb','ccc']);
console.log(u.next().value); // returns generator object
```

Not exactly what we want. But it sort of makes sense since the first yield returns a yield. So we process each yield as a generator object? Lets see:

```
var u = upper(['aaa','bbb','ccc']);
console.log(u.next().value.next().value.next().value); // works
console.log(u.next().value.next().value.next().value); // doesn't work
```

OK. Let's figure out why the second call doesn't work.

The upper function:

```
function *upper (items) {
  yield* items.mapGen(/*...*/);
}
```

yields the return value of `mapGen()`. For now, let's ignore what `mapGen` does and just think about what `yield` actually means.

So the first time we call `.next()` the function is paused here:

```
function *upper (items) {
  yield* items.mapGen(/*...*/); // <----- yields value and paused
}
```

which is the first `console.log()`. The second time we call `.next()` the function call continue at the line after the `yield`:

```
function *upper (items) {
  yield* items.mapGen(/*...*/);
  // <----- function call resumes here
}
```

which returns (not yield since there's no yield keyword on that line) nothing (undefined).

This is why the second `console.log()` fails: the `*upper()` function has run out of objects to yield. Indeed, it only ever yields once so it has only one object to yield - it is a generator that generates only one value.

OK. So we can do it like this:

```
var u = upper(['aaa','bbb','ccc']);
var uu = u.next().value; // the only value that upper will ever return
console.log(uu.next().value.next().value); // works
console.log(uu.next().value.next().value); // works
console.log(uu.next().value.next().value); // works
```

Yay! But, if this is the case, how can the innermost `yield` in the callback work?

Well, if you think carefully you'll realize that the innermost `yield` in the callback also behaves like the `yield` in `*upper()` - it will only ever return one value. But we never use it more than once. That's  because the second time we call `uu.next()` we're not returning the same callback but another callback which in turn will also ever return only one value.

So it works. Or it can be made to work. But it's kind of stupid.

### Conclusion:

After all this, the key point to realize about why `yield` doesn't work the way we expected is that `yield` pauses code execution and resumes execution on the next line. If there are no more yields then the generator terminates (is `.done`).

Second point to realize is that callbacks and all those Array methods (`.map`, `.forEach` etc.) aren't magical. They're just javascript functions. As such it's a bit of a mistake to think of them as control structures like `for` or `while`.

### Epilogue

There is a way to make `mapGen` work cleanly:

```
function upper (items) {
  return items.mapGen(function (item) {
    try {
      return item.toUpperCase()
    } catch (e) {
      return 'null'
    }
  })
}
var u = upper(['aaa','bbb','ccc']);
console.log(u.next().value);
console.log(u.next().value);
console.log(u.next().value);
```

But you'll notice that in this case we return form the callback (not yield) and we also return form `upper`. So this case devolves back into a `yield` inside a for loop which isn't what we're discussing.

Comment: I've never used yield so the last example may be wrong. It probably needs a return instead of a yield.

Comment: You would want to use `yield* items.mapGen(...)` in the last example. Or make `upper` a normal function and `return items.mapGen(...)`.

Comment: No go. It still chokes on `yield item.toUpperCase()` [Gist - solution.js](https://gist.github.com/gyaresu/2960e6e8add528940bfb)

Comment: @gyaresu: Ah yeah. The callback to `mapGen` should not contain `yield` in this case. It should just be a `return`.

Comment: After playing around with this I've come to the conclusion that it just doesn't work with callbacks because it doesn't make sense. Note: it may look like it should make sense to humans but if you think like the interpreter you'll find that it doesn't make sense. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another method by "co - npm": co.wrap(fn*)

```
function doSomething(){
    return new promise()
}

var fn = co.wrap(function* (arr) {
  var data = yield arr.map((val) => {
    return doSomething();
});
return data;
});
fn(arr).then(function (val) {
 consloe.log(val)
});
```